# What kind of "how to use ingredient X" questions are appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is in regard to a question I just posted:

[Recommended cooking uses for applejack?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/668/recommended-cooking-uses-for-applejack) .

It's a "how can I use ingredient X" question, which I imagine we'll see a lot of. It's an area of perennial interest to me, since I do tend to pick up these special-case ingredients over time, and I need to get a lot better at utilizing these cooking resources I already have. (Think of it as DRY applied to cooking, I suppose. ;-) ) Furthermore, it's an area that seems to me poorly served by existing recipe sources.

After reading this exchange about recipe trolling:

[Should "I need a recipe for X?" questions be off-topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic)

I'm on the fence on whether this kind of question should be off-charter or not. It wasn't my intention to troll for specific recipes. On the other hand, it's certainly got a significant subjective component to it, and could easily degenerate into a "list of recipes that use X" kind of thread.

What are your thoughts on how/if these kinds of questions might be appropriate? Is there a particular way you would have preferred to see me approach the question in the topic mentioned above?

Answer (score 5):

I think "how to use x" is definitely the kind of thing people search for, so having questions like this could be useful (it's certainly the sort of things *I'm* interested in).

On the other hand, there's no definitive answer, so it's probably best to make questions like this community wiki and not accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on context of what you are asking. Take a quick look at [[my response here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/restaurant-mimicry-questions-allowed/70#70)] about the "indiscriminate" nature of list-of-X questions.

So how do you tell if *“how to use ingredient X”* appropriate? It depends on what you are asking.

If you ask *"recommend uses for chocolate?"*, that is most definitely a list-of-X question. It's a poll asked indiscriminately, and not really what I would expect on this site.

If you ask *"How to use <some-really-weird-spice-I-never-heard-of>?"*, that is a really specific question. You are seeking knowledge. The answers will be the product of experience or expertise. It is *not* an indiscriminate question.

Can you see the difference?