# Are questions on alcohol beverages allowed?

Tags: discussion, alcohol

Is it allowed to ask questions on:

- wine (eg. does red wine suits to chicken?)
- vodka (eg. how to make herbal liqueur from vodka?)
- beer (eg. what kind of beer is best for Beer Can Chicken - I know its not a great example)
- etc.

Comment: I think it might be the only way to actually find out what *the majority* thinks. And not just what you and I think :)

Comment: Just one more thing I'd like people to think about. Out of 250 questions, how many were related to [alcoholic] beverages? How many before these discussions popped up on meta today? I know that this is far from being a reason *in and of itself* to close the door on a subject, but it's still important: **Is this subject so near and dear to all of us, so important to the site's success that we'd be shooting ourselves in the foot if we left it out?** Those advocating its inclusion: are you *sure* you're thinking about what's best for the *site* - and not what *you* happen to be interested in?

Comment: @Aaronaught: Given that I didn't ask any drinks questions before seeing this topic, I think I can safely say "yes". With the possible exception of questions pertaining to coffee, for which I have a *huge* blind spot (and yet which is clearly the least controversial of the drinks questions I've asked...)

Comment: (I removed the vote-posts, as people didn't just vote yes OR no)

Comment: @Aaronaught: Your implication that we should need a reason _not to_ close an entire branch of subject matter is just backwards. If that were the default stance and mindset then we'd need a discussion on just about every topic in existence, to vet whether it's "allowed" to be on-topic. That's just plain _silly_. You can't just come to the table and say "Xxxx should be off topic. Explain to me why it should not be." Regarding my particular interests, not much. I don't have a lot of knowledge on the subject. I have a book on mixing drinks that I consult occasionally, that's about it.

Comment: My reasons for "advocating it's inclusion" stem from a fundamental dislike for arbitrary regulations decided by a minority of the community, as well as being unable to see any merit behind the hollow reasons put forth thus far for it's prohibition. Also, what does the amount of questions have to do with this discussion? Nothing. The discussion is whether or not alcoholic beverage questions are on or off-topic. The quantity of questions asked thus far is irrelevant, and a hollow argument.

Comment: Also I've noticed that no one has mentioned tags in this discussion (or I've missed it). I think the appropriate thing to do at this point in time is to tag alcohol related questions appropriately, and comment referencing this discussion. Only when an _overwhelming majority_ of people have decided this debate one way or the other should we take steps to close.

Comment: (I did miss it) Brendan mentioned them here: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121/are-questions-on-alcohol-beverages-allowed/159#159 but was downvoted.

Comment: @hobodave: I've already given *several* reasons why the subject *should* be excluded.  I'm simply refuting one of the most common reasons I've read for why it *shouldn't* be - that excluding it would somehow make the site less valuable or useful or cut off an important part of our audience.

Comment: Also @hobodave, I can clearly see your rationale now; it's the canonical inclusionist, everything should be allowed unless an "overwhelming majority" doesn't want it.  Unfortunately, that's an exceptionally poor recipe for real-world success.

Comment: @Knives: Your response confuses me.  Are you saying you don't care about mixers but you do care about coffee, or vice versa?  (If the latter, what is this "huge blind spot?")

Comment: @Aaronaught: Yes, you've given several good reasons why it should be in your answer below. I wasn't implying that you hadn't. In your comment above that I replied to, it seemed like you were putting forth additional invalid reasons. The reasons you give in your answer are valid, I just disagree.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I'm saying I'm probably biased toward including coffee because I enjoy it daily and spend a fair bit of time experimenting with different varieties and roasts, whereas I don't spend a lot of time mixing drinks. I've tried to come up with fairly broad, representational questions on various drink-related topics (alcoholic, non-alcoholic), but my actual interests may be skewing the results toward the one I actually intend to ask/answer questions in going forward.

Comment: @Knives: Well, I guess it depends on the specific coffee questions.  Coffee beans are a food, and roasting them is a cooking technique (like roasting nuts).  On the other hand, a question about espresso makers is definitely veering toward off-topic territory, if not way over the line.

Comment: To me it seems that the exclusion of alcoholic beverages has different motivations for different people. For some it might not be ok, because it is a drug, for others because it is not halal etc. On what grounds is the discussion led? I think if it is for religious dietary reasons, it might be difficult to exclude, as a lot of food is forbidden under a specific religion as well. There is not much left if you adhere to halal, kosher, hindu and ecologically motivated veganism. If it is purely, because alcohol is a drug, then this is worth discussion, however I would be against prohibition.

Answer (score 35):

It's rather unsettling to see a group of people eager to deem a broad set of questions as patently off-topic.

Brewing & making spirits? Sure that's off-topic, because it has nothing to do with food or cooking.

However, I've seen in a couple perfectly reasonable questions about drink making the **Prohibition Posse** has come in full force calling for closure.

I've grabbed 5 dead-tree cookbooks off my bookshelf and flipped through. Four of those five include either a section, or at least a few scattered cocktail recipes.

Additionally, "being simple to google", as another answer stated as a reason, has *never* been a valid reason to deem something off-topic in any Stack* community.

---

I'm wary of the motivations behind this leaning towards "banning" alcohol related questions.

If they are moral reasons, then I think you should keep your morals to yourself and not impose them on this community. (**Edit**: I do not currently believe that this is anyone's actual reason for wanting to ban this topic.)

If the reasons stem from being a control freak and enjoying having a little niche of this community that you can feel proud of for controlling, and giving you something to do, then I don't have anything nice to say.

If the reasons are simply an honest belief that they are probably off-topic to "Food & Cooking", then this is reasonable. I just think you're wrong for the reasons stated above. Food & Drink in most cultures throughout the ages are strongly coupled.

Comment: +1 well said hobodave

Comment: I think that drinks are off topic. The site isn't called "Food, Drinks & Cooking" :)
I think that the scope of the site would change too much if all drink-questions are allowed.

I don't care what or how often people drink -- God knows, I love going to a cocktail bar.

Comment: Do you just mean alcoholic drinks should be off topic, or any beverage?  Things like smoothies are often treated as meals in themselves, but are certainly a beverage.

Comment: I actually think I'd vote most beverage-questions as off-topic.

Comment: So to get recommendations on smoothies I'm going to have to go to smoothieoverflow.com?  I don't see how you are making this distinction between things you ingest for nutritional value.

Comment: -1 for your blatantly inflammatory remarks.  My reasons have nothing to do with "prohibition".  They have to do with the fact that **drinks are not food.**  Not to mention what I've said before - if you want alcohol-related questions then brewing/winemaking is a lot closer to actual cooking than mixing drinks.  It makes **no** sense to claim that brewing/winemaking should be off-topic but then to turn around and say you want cocktail questions.  How is that better?  How does it have **any** more to do with **food** or **cooking**?

Comment: @Aaronaught: I'm sorry you felt personally attacked by my undirected statements. I don't claim to know your reasons, nor do I make assumptions. I listed what I thought 3 possible reasons were, and what my opinions of those reasons were. You clearly fall into the 3rd reason I suggested, so why are you so offended? Regarding the "drinks are not food", it's just silly. I am actually a seasoned brewer. I checked all the books in my brewing library, none of them include a cocktail recipe. Yet, as previously stated, most of my cookbooks include cocktail recipes. Food and drink are the same. Period.

Comment: Alright, easy google-ability aside. I have *nothing* against alcohol.  I still think that "what is the best recipe for _____ drink" should be off topic. I'm 100% OK with questions like "what's the best way to muddle mint" or even "what's the best way to infuse vodka?"

Comment: @Kevin: Maybe you will choose different examples after this, but I think that nearly all three of those are _subjective_ and should be closed. The most egregious being the drink one. That question is as patently stupid as "What is the best recipe for risotto?"

Comment: I disagree, and think that there likely *is* a best way to muddle mint or infuse vodka, but at least we're not disagreeing on the same topic as before!

Comment: @hobodave: "I don't claim to know your reasons, nor do I make assumptions."  That's exactly what you did when you started off with the "prohibition posse" nickname.  I'm not personally offended, but I have a problem with people making arguments based on what they perceive to be the (likely) intent of the people arguing, as opposed to the actual merits of the argument.  I would like to keep these debates about the important things: Mainly, whether or not they help further the mission of the site at a fundamental level and what any unintended (or intended) effects of the questions would be.

Comment: How I see is it that 1) Drinks are something people make in the kitchen in almost the exact same way as certain foods (take ingredients, mix, possibly add some 'flair') and 2) It's not like having a broad scope will hurt the community. StackOverflow gets a wide range of topics that I wouldn't call "programming", and no one closes questions because "math doesn't belong on a programming site".

Comment: @Brendan: What are you talking about?  Math questions **have** been closed on Stack Overflow.  What topics does it get that you wouldn't call programming that don't get closed or at least spark animated disputes?  Having an overly broad scope **does** hurt the community; it's been proven time and time again.  The issue to decide is whether or not the inclusion of *this* topic *makes* the scope too broad - or too inconsistent.

Comment: I also agree. I've never hosted a dinner party where I didn't want to serve drinks alongside food, and I consider them one event. I think the line is drawn at recipe requests, a line shared with foods.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Prohibition Posse doesn't imply any assumptions on my part for your reasoning. It's simply a convenient label given the subject matter, plus I'm fond of alliteration. :) However, it does accurately describe what you and a handful of others have taken upon yourself to do. Which is go around voting to close alcohol related questions based solely on this (prior to yesterday) relatively inactive topic. It's not even apparent that much more than 10 or 15 people have even _read_ this discussion.

Comment: @hobodave: Indeed you're right, it's a relatively inactive topic - something that really wasn't that controversial and *seemed* to already have an answer in the definition phase.  Only when it was suggested that we make it "official" did a small minority of people react by starting several questions on the subject (which were promptly closed) as well as several debates about its validity.  Debate is healthy, I have no problem with us hashing this out, but I have a problem with your subtle (and in some cases not-so-subtle) ad-hominems.  Who is **really** the cranky minority here?

Comment: @Aaronaught: It actually was controversial. In most questions that were closed there were several comments indicating confusion and disagreement as to why it was off topic. However, those voting to close provided no reference to this meta topic. Yes, people seem to have intentionally asked a few questions regarding alcoholic beverages seemingly in response to this topic. I don't think that should come as a surprise. It's not unusual for some to show distrust and dislike of a perceived misguided use of power/authority by doing that which is prohibited. That said, the questions were well put.

Comment: Regarding my ad-hominem usage, I assure you it was not intended. I wasn't trying to imply that because individuals may or may not find alcohol morally acceptable that their opinions were invalid. My intent, that I thought was put rather clearly, was to convey that _if that were_ the reasoning, then that is an invalid reason to deem something off-topic to this site. And again, prohibition posse was just available, easy, and sounds good :) I believe you and do not think you or jmoeller are in anyway supporters of prohibition of alcohol by a State.

Comment: Cranky? I guess, I prefer passionate though. As to minority? Well, that has yet to be determined.

Comment: @hobodave: I can only speak for the one that I voted to close, and although I didn't link to this meta, I did add a comment and later on suggest taking the discussion to meta.  If other people voted to close other questions without any comments, that's an issue of etiquette.  The prevailing thought on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange today is that it is *polite* but not *required* to explain close votes.  Also, with respect to so-called "[ab]use of power/authority" - don't we all have the same power/authority at this point?

Comment: @Aaronaught: Yes, I agree that it's not required. I do consider it rather impolite if no reason is given at all. I do not approve of your paraphrasing of my quote. I actually typed it that way at first, then thought about it. I don't think there has been any abuse, and I thought it was too strong a word. Why misguided? I think that accurately describes the actions taken based on a topic that had relatively little community input. Abuse? Definitely not, specifically because we _do_ have the same power/authority.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're on about.  The whole point of *creating* the topic was to *get community input.*  No decisions were made.  No "power" was involved.

Answer (score 9):

Questions related to food and wine, possibly other beverages, do go together. As such. I see no potential harm in asking specific questions, regarding this pairing. The problem is, what constitutes 'specific'?

Is a question such as "Can I serve red wine with fish" purely subjective?

In a similar vein "I'm making hot curry and I need a white wine to serve, which grape variety would be best?

Answer (score 7):

I would answer this question "sometimes."

This question is too broad to answer definitely yes or no on. I vote to break this question down to categories that *do* make more sense to make individual yes/no decisions on, refactoring to generalize outside of alcoholic beverages where appropriate, and then go from there.

Here's my take at a breakdown, based on topics touched on this thread:

1. Alcohol In Cooking Food
2. Beverage Making and Cooking
   2.1. Brewing, fermenting drinks, and distilling (beer, wine, liquor, root beer, kombucha)
   2.2. Everything else (cocktails, soda, infusions, tea, coffee, shakes, smoothies, juice)
3. Meal Selection and Planning
   3.1. Beverage/food pairing
   3.2. Balancing of flavors across dishes
   3.3. Dietary/nutrition planning
4. Food Presentation
   4.1. Plating
   4.2. Garnishes

Comment: Unfortunately the vast majority of "yea" voters seem to think that 2.1 is off-topic but 2.2 is on-topic, and don't see anything odd or contradictory about this.  So even though I personally agree with your assessment, I don't think it's going to help here.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I think it's difficult to tease out what people specifically think about 2.1. vs. 2.2. because the discussion on this thread is all over the map at the moment, and the votes are coming in on whole constellations of issues at once. I want people to think about what the right distinctions are to be made between these topics before tallying voltes.

Comment: I'm one of the 2.1 is off-topic, 2.2 is on-topic crowd.  While I'd love to see questions on 2.1, the process is more removed from food and cooking as much of the work is removed from actually eating it (I would make the same argument about cheese-making).  Other than that, 3.3 is the only other I would call off-topic.

Comment: @Aaronaught, 2.1: Chefs don't generally make their own beer. 2.2: Chefs frequently do make their own drinks. The distinction should be based on the audience of the site, and the intended audience knows about one but not necessarily about the other. And I agree that this should be broken down. Trying to discuss such a huge variety of things is difficult.

Comment: @Brendan: Specious reasoning.  The ratio of chefs who make their own beer to chefs who make their own cocktails is equivalent to the ratio of *anyone else* making their own beer to making their own cocktails.  There's no reason to believe that chefs are any more "experts" on this.  I could also say that most chefs listen to music but don't play an instrument.  That's obviously true but not very important.

Comment: @Aaronaught, perhaps it wasn't the best phrasing, I should've added something about expectations. The best I can think of "Being able to brew beer doesn't make you a better chef, but being able to make drinks/smoothies does".

Comment: @Aaronaught, I think the food/drink distinction is somewhat arbitrary and not helpful, because you want to ban a category of questions not because it's not helpful for chefs, or because it's not the exact same method as cooking, but because the result is liquid. What if I want to make a jus to add to my meat? What if I just want to drink it? Now it's a beverage. Similarly, what if I want to make orange juice, carrot juice or tomato juice to add to a recipe? It's the exact same as making a drink, but I'm not drinking it. If I add "to put on my steak", does that make any beverage question ok?

Answer (score 6):

The more specific we make the topic of this site, the less useful it becomes. What does it matter if making beverages isn't "cooking"? Maybe we should change the theme to "food preparation" rather than "cooking" to make it more clear, but having beverage-related questions doesn't hurt the site, and banning them will just push people away.

Why not tag all beverage-related questions with `beverage` and let the people who hate liquids add that tag to their "Ignored Tags"?

Edit for clarity: 
Drink preparation is very similar to food preparation, and having both won't over-extend the scope of the site. The important part is that almost all of the people who are expert cooks also know a lot about making drinks.

Comment: You're incorrect. The more specialized a site is, the **more likely it is to attract real experts** and therefore the **more** useful it becomes. Without focus, you have Yahoo Answers. Please don't start trotting out the "ignored tags" workaround already; it's been beaten to death already on Stack Overflow and most people have learned their lesson from that: Don't wait to decide on a topic's sanctioned status. It's not relevant whether or not people *like* the booze questions. Trust me, I *like* booze. What's important is the tone that a proliferation of such questions sets for new visitors.

Comment: P.S. My -1 vote is specifically for the ignored tags bit.  Your first paragraph is something I merely disagree with; however, advocating that people start ignoring tags before the site even goes live is actively harmful to the site's long-term survival.

Comment: @Aaronaught, most expert cooks are going to know how to make drinks. My point isn't that site should be for everything, but that 'cooking' is already a fairly narrow topic, and drink preparation is almost exactly the same. And what's wrong with ignoring tags? The exist so you can not be bothered by something you're not interested in. If someone's not interested in beverage-related questions, they should set the site to ignore them. On my first day on StackOverflow, I set 20+ ignore tags and I don't consider the site any worse because it has content I'm not interested in.

Comment: The point is that this is not the appropriate time to be ignoring tags. This is the beta period, where we need to decide as a community what should be in scope. If somebody disagrees with the community **then** they can decide to ignore the tags. You're falling back on the same ridiculous premise that's been debunked hundreds of times on SO/MSO, mainly that people who don't want a certain topic, don't want it because they "hate" the topic and can't stand to read about it. Nothing could be further from the truth. I love cocktails, but questions about them hinder the real mission of this site.

Comment: I didn't say people who don't like it hate it, I said if you're not interested in something you can ignore it. I feel like the community should define guidelines strict enough to keep the site focused, but there's no reason to be so strict that everyone agrees on topic. It's perfectly fine for there to be beverage-related questions for a subset of users who are interested even if 90% of users will never look at those questions. It doesn't hurt the scope, but I don't see how a separate "beverage perpetration" site would be more helpful than just including it here.

Answer (score 4):

I think that **home brewing** wine or other alcoholic drinks **is obviously off topic**. Also  generic wine-oriented questions seem off topic (e.g "California wines are better than South African wines?").

**Pairing** is really food and cooking oriented that **can't be off topic**! Of course could be a bit subjective but this is always true in food and cooking (it is not engineering!).

Some **beverage preparation** (e.g *Iced Coffee* or *Bicerin*) are quite on topic.

**Cocktail preparation** is not much on topic, but it does not add noise and having such questions could not harm at all this site.

Comment: +1: I agree with all your points. The way you've stated your last sentence has also made me realize that this topic is probably entirely too broad. Perhaps if this topic stays inconclusive, or even is decided that it _is_ on topic, someone could still start another discussion directly relating to the on/off-topicness of _specifically_ cocktail preparation. I'm not sure where I'd fall there, probably lean towards on-topic. Yet, I wouldn't feel some grave atrocity had been committed if the community decided they weren't.

Comment: Pairing has nothing to do with cooking.  Serving, maybe.  Not cooking.  Yes, it has to do with "food", but if the site was about food in general then we'd have crap like restaurant reviews included as part of the subject matter.

Comment: @Aaronaught: every chef would agree to the fact that serving is an important part of cooking.

Comment: Oh, you speak for every chef now do you?  *Serving is an important part of cooking?*  Repeating this mantra in various forms does not make it any truer.

Comment: @Aaronaught: it is true indeed. At cooking schools professional cooks are taught serving.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I concur with Lorenzo, with the obs. that there are several elements that go into serving. I've tried to make those distinctions in my response in case we want to debate those distinctions separately.

Answer (score 3):

If you can consume it as part of a meal - it should be allowed in.  The steps required to source, prepare, cook and clean up after should also be fair game.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think brewing / distillation needs to be on-topic, although I'd love to see some examples of edge-cases if someone can think of any. Similarly, growing wheat is off-topic, while using flour isn't, and milling...?

I will be rather unhappy though, if drink-mixing questions are off-topic, *especially* if the ultra-subjective "pairing" questions are allowed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you consider drink-mixing to be relevant to a Food & Cooking site?  Questions about making specific drinks are effectively recipe-swapping (already considered off-topic), so the only remaining questions would be on things like specific gravities, mixing techniques and equipment, garnishes and so on.  While these aren't actively *harmful*, it might be very difficult to confine the scope this way and avoid an explosion of alcohol-related questions.  Surely drink mixing is even *farther* away from cooking than beer brewing, isn't it?

Comment: P.S. I've made a small revision to my answer. After thinking about it, I've decided to take a more definite stance against pairing questions, primarily because they are bikeshed questions by definition.  I can't think of a single example that's appropriate for a Q&A site.  I still think mixing is off-topic, but food/wine pairing is actually much worse.

Comment: @Aaronaught: IMHO, drink-mixing is effectively the same as many other food-related questions, and should be handled equivalently: you might consider a recipe-centered question on making the canonical caesar salad (or a health-centered question on using raw eggs in the dressing) off-topic, but that shouldn't disallow questions on coddling the eggs or preparing the croutons for said salad.

Comment: I'm with Knives here, drink-mixing questions such as techniques are very relevant to the site.  Something as simple as "Do I use sweet or dry vermouth in a martini?" does not go to recipe swapping, but is general knowledge related to food.  This may not be "cooking" but it definitely is food preparation.

Comment: How is it the same?  What's the bartending equivalent of coddling eggs or making croutons for a Caesar salad?

Comment: @plor: No it's not.  Drinks are not food.  We already have proposals in Area 51 for bartending and drink mixing.

Comment: I think drink-questions should go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4141/bartending-and-alcoholic-beverages) as well.

Comment: @Aaronaught Where do questions about lemonade go then?

Comment: +1: See my answer: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121/are-questions-on-alcohol-beverages-allowed/151#151

Comment: @Aaronaught: how about [muddling mint](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/978/whats-the-proper-way-to-muddle-mint-for-a-julep-or-mojito)?

Comment: @plor: Huh?  Lemonade questions don't belong on a cooking site either.  I don't know "where" they go - somewhere else.

Comment: @Knives: Still doesn't seem to have much to do with cooking, from where I stand.  Food is something you can eat.  Cooking is the art of preparing foods.  This isn't even tangentially related, it just happens to involve a food-like ingredient.  That doesn't count, in the same way that wine as an ingredient doesn't somehow make a cooking question *off*-topic.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I guess I don't draw that much of a distinction between food / beverage, eating / drinking. Does a thick milkshake become on-topic if you eat it with a spoon? Does soup become off-topic if I plan to drink it from a thermos instead of eating it from a bowl? If I make eggnog with a custard instead of raw eggs, does that change the appropriateness of a question regarding its construction? It's too fine a line to bother drawing, IMHO...

Comment: @Knives: The thing is, nobody actually *thinks* about these things, because the answer is obvious.  Soup is a food, not a drink.  Eggnog is a drink, not a food.  Ice cream is a food, milkshakes are drinks.  Sure, maybe if you try to *break it down* the line starts to become blurry, but I think almost everybody naturally knows the difference without thinking about it.  You're approaching this like a programmer, not a cook.

Comment: @Aaronaught: if the answer was obvious, we wouldn't be discussing it. You might be right - I certainly can't speak for anyone but myself - but the more I think about it, the harder it gets for me to come up with an easy to communicate rule that would cleanly divide these topics. Making yogurt falls on one side but making kefir falls on the other? It reminds me more and more of the whole "web apps" fiasco on SU...

Comment: Perhaps it's a cultural thing, but in my country just as much attention is paid to the wine used in the kitchen as served at the table. Just as much attention is given to the choice of wine for a given type of food. Basically, it's virtually impossible to consider one without the other. In my experience, if one were to take 5 decent sommeliers and ask them to pair a wine with a given type of food, the end result would be virtually unanimous. Personally, I know nothing about cocktails, so I wouldn't try to answer those questions. I would hope others do likewise regarding wine.

Comment: @Knives: If you eat it with a utensil or your hands, it's food.  If you drink it or suck it through a straw, it's a drink.  Sounds simple to me.  Can you think of any notable examples that don't clearly fall into one or the other, that we wouldn't be able to deal with on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @Pulse: I'm sure a lot of attention is paid to the choice of wine, but being of equal importance to the food does not make it food.  And with respect to your comment about wine pairings, I'm calling BS; they have major sommelier competitions and "summits" where the top sommeliers all give wildly different answers given the same food.  Did you mean to say "speculation" where you said "experience" or have you actually tested this?

Comment: @Aaronaught Being an Oenologist and having had numerous conversations with like minded people I can say experience and not "speculation"

Comment: @Pulse: I'm not questioning your knowledge or experience, only the evidence for this particular claim. Unless you or one of your colleagues has tested this hypothesis, I maintain that the plural of anecdote is not data and that wine pairing is far too subjective a topic for a Q&A site. Also, given the immense number of wines and wineries, I would be concerned about such questions inviting spammy answers (which would be difficult to positively identify).

Comment: @Aaronaught: now you've disconnected it from the food itself. "How can I make a tasty, clear stock?" is about stock. It shouldn't matter if I intend to drink it or use it as an ingredient. Moreover, if I *say* I intend to drink it, it doesn't prevent the answers from being useful for someone who wants a clear stock for use as an ingredient. Spoon or straw, it has no bearing on the substance itself.

Comment: @Knives: The author's intent as far as ingestion methods are concerned is not really relevant.  They can use it as a suppository for all I care.  What's relevant is whether or not it's a subject that an expert cook/chef is likely to know or care about, which is based on the *common usage*.  Stock is something that cooks work with.  A Manhattan is not.  The same group of people can answer a question about the former, even if the intent is a little odd. The latter is targeted toward a completely different audience.

Comment: This is getting out of control. I got a vote to close on a question about using a blender with a link to this discussion as a reason. Until there is a site for beverages, I see no reason to exclude them from here. Cooking shows do stuff with beverages all the time (alcoholic or not). On Iron Chef, for example, it's not uncommon for them to prepare a drink with a particular dish. I see little difference between questions on drinks and questions on knife maintenance. They are perhaps not the core of the site, but they are ancillary and have no better place at this time.

Comment: Also, that was not an invitation to start closing questions about knives and other tools. I think in general we should adopt a policy of being as inclusive as possible, instead of exclusionary. If a fringe topic starts to dominate the site, then maybe work to help them get their own site or take other steps to bring focus back on the main topic.

Comment: @Ryan: "I think in general we should adopt a policy of being as inclusive as possible" - bad idea.  If a fringe topic starts to dominate the site, then it's already too late to do anything about it.  That doesn't mean we should be *exclusionary* either, but there has to be some sense of balance, we cannot say "anything goes" and expect to be successful in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

"How do I make homemade wine?" was voted off-topic [on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking/2284#2284).

I don't think questions like that one, or like the one [you posted](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-chill-beer-quick) are appropriate.

"what kind of beer is best for Beer Can Chicken" and "does red wine suits to chicken?" might be appropriate, maybe with a wiki-sticker.

Comment: -1: The how to chill beer quickly is no more off-topic than a "how do I thaw ice cream quickly" question that was also asked

Comment: One is about something you eat (food) the other one is not.

Comment: if you thaw the icecream too quickly, you'll pretty much be stuck drinking it... Also, what about milkshakes?

Comment: That's a rather petty distinction. What is eating? What is food? Is food only a solid? What about soup? What about lemonade? If you want to get really nitpicky (which I assume you do based on your reply), food is simply a substance that is edible and provides positive caloric value. Mixed drinks, and heck, even 200 proof grain alcohol fit this. Alcohol is broken down into sugar and then digested as such. Engaging in a debate as to what constitutes "food" just brings everyone full circle back to "stupid". (the debate, not you)

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing another thought into the mix.

The consensus seems to be that Brewing is obviously not cooking. I contest this. Home brewing is generally started in the kitchen, it can involve different ingredients and methods, and is at least as related to cooking as jam making and pickling which we do seem to have questions on.

In the same way, making ice cream or lemonade is not cooking but would probably be allowed. One of which involves no solids and the other no heating up.

I would say that questions on brewing should be allowed as they involve preparing a consumable item.

Comment: Even if brewing is cooking, I think it is too wide a topic to be included in a site about cooking, and it has its own proposal on A51. if you want to brew beer then add your voice to that proposal.

Comment: And if you want to allow questions on consumable items, should we allow questions on preparation of home medications?

Comment: @Sam  Are the medications herbal/food based? Tea, spice mixes, tinctures (herbs/spices in alcohol), herbs/spices in oil, evolved in many cases because of their beneficial nutritional components.  Indeed, separating taste from health is not really possible, since our very anatomy is designed to discern and extract nutrtition from food..  Was it Hippocrates who said, "Let your food be your medicine?"

Comment: I admit the "brewing is not cooking" thing really surprises me, I'm seeing a lot of overlap myself... considering pickling (fermentation) and canning (equipment sterilization, etc) are on topic, and require as much or more specialization than, and a *lot* of the same techniques as, say, making an easy mead.  I could see a suggestion that it might want its own place due to specialization, but the underlying techniques are, really, the same.

Answer (score 0):

Drink mixing questions seem to be very easy to google, and amount essentially to a recipe request; It seems to me they should be off topic, but I'm open to arguments to the contrary.

Pairing seems like it should also be off topic, as it can be far subjective and argumentative.

Update: Let's ignore the google-ability. I still think that blatant requests for recipes are off topic.

I should clarify: I have no problem with technique or ingredient related questions.

Comment: Despite having answered a mixed drink question, and getting some reputation as a result, I'm inclined to agree, going forward!

Comment: -1: See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121/are-questions-on-alcohol-beverages-allowed/151#151

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Mixed drink recipe requests are obviously off-topic, because recipe requests are off topic. But what about mixed drink questions that aren't asking for a recipe?

Comment: @ Brendan Long: I wouldn't say I'm missing the point; you and I agree that mixed-drink recipe requests are obviously off-topic, but our opinion is not universally held. This question was reopened: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/960/what-is-a-proper-manhattan

As the last sentence in my answer intends to point out, I have no problem with mixed-drink questions that are not recipe-requests.