# Why are questions about making wine/mead/beer deleted?

Tags: discussion, recipe, alcohol

It seems like the process of making wine and similar is about using food ingredients to make a food product. Are questions about this subject disallowed for some other reason(s)?

Comment: Scope issues aside, the question was closed, not deleted.  Closed questions are still visible to everyone and can be commented on/edited, they just don't accept new answers.

Comment: Hi Alex, I closed it. Perhaps I should have waited a bit longer for the community to pick it up. My apologies for that. Also, closed questions can be reopened by the community if they so feel fit.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "we" don't want them here. The community has nearly unanimously decided they are off-topic since the original definition of this site.

Simply searching for "brewing" will find these and more:

- [Are questions on alcohol beverages allowed?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/are-questions-on-alcohol-beverages-allowed)
- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain)
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking/2284#2284

Those interested in winemaking/brewing should be committing to the relevant Area51 proposal here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/beer-and-wine-brewing

However, even that site isn't successful, they still don't belong here.

If you disagree and would like to argue your point, I kindly ask that you use one or more of the existing topics instead of this one.

Comment: What you mean "we" white man?  Personally I think we're barking up the wrong tree trying to restrict the definition of the site as much as possible.  What we're going to end up with is a smaller commmunity that is less active.  If we broadened the topic we'd have more users - period - which means more people to answer questions.  I may have a primary interest in brewing, but still be able to answer plenty of questions on other cooking/food topics.  You make me take my brewing questions to the brewing SE and I won't be here to answer those other questions.

Comment: I recognize I've been in the minority on this since definition.  But the more I see people cringe against the restricted topic and strict moderation the more convinced I become that we need to widen the topic and loosen the moderation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the recent question stating that someone had made some champaigne (technically, they made a sparkling wine), and was asking about other alcoholic beverages they could make, I'm not the one who deleted it (I was waiting to see community response), but I personally thought it was inappropriate just because it was too broad.

Imagine I asked a question:

- I made a lasagne last week, and it was really good, what other Italian food can I cook?
- I made a pilaf last week, what other rice dishes can I make?
- I made a lentil curry last week, what other vegetarian dishes can I make?

All of these are blatantly too broad, and should be closed at the very least, if not deleted as well.

Comment: I think Mike closed the question himself.  And it wasn't actually deleted.  I don't think that anyone other than myself and some of the moderators are actually using delete votes...

Comment: I'm the culprit. I forgot that one vote from me closed it. Next time I'll wait a bit longer.

Comment: @Mike: Don't fret, it would have been closed anyway.  Not only was it ridiculously vague, even for a poll, but wine making is considered off-topic even by the most vocal proponents of [alcoholic] beverage questions.

Comment: @Mike Sherov: Yea I wouldn't worry about it if it's something that's a universal no-no. If you find yourself thinking "Hmm, this _might_ be on topic" then you might want to exercise caution.