# Are questions about equipment off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been a few questions about knives, and these seem on topic but a [question about an ice cream maker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/932/kitchenaid-stand-mixer-international-attachment-compatibility) part, is this on or off topic?  and for what reason?

Comment: FWIW, the question was a little bit more broad in scope than just an ice cream maker part - he's asking about general compatibility of Kitchen Aid mixer attachments, of which there are many (the ice cream maker was the first example, but he also mentions a slicer/shredder and a food grinder). The initials confuse this more than is necessary; shame I can't edit...

Answer (score 13):

It's not fair to expect every member (especially new members) to understand such subtle differences between on-topic equipment and off-topic equipment.  If some kitchen appliances are considered on topic (stoves, ovens, mixers, food processors, slow cookers, etc.) then all kitchen appliances should be on topic.

The only difference I can really see between an ice cream maker and a crock pot is that an ice cream maker has a highly-specialized purpose.  But that's not a very good or reliable distinction because the gray area is pretty big - a crêpe pan is obviously not the most versatile piece of equipment, but I think almost everyone here would agree that it's a good fit for this site.

There *are* a few things I dislike about the linked question.  Specifically:

- It's not just about a specific *type* of equipment, but a specific *model*.  This limits the audience considerably, and a large number of similar posts might set the stage for a never-ending stream of "which appliance is better, X or Y?" type questions.
- It's not about the **use** of the equipment but rather **acquisition and assembly**, which is starting to drift pretty far away from questions that will teach people how to be better cooks (which is, after all, the goal of the site, right?).
- It's relative to a specific geographical area - two of them, actually - which makes it a candidate for closing as `Too Localized`.  However, the areas are pretty broad (Europe and USA) and this doesn't seriously shrink the audience.  Unless we started getting inundated with similar questions, I would hold off on the TL vote for now.

Of the above three points, probably the second is the most important.  Right now, though, I just don't think it's a strong enough point to move the question into off-topic territory.  It's a question that, IMO, is unlikely to get answered very quickly on a site like this, but it's still a valid question.

As far as I'm concerned, **questions about kitchen equipment are on topic** - as long as they meet the other criteria (i.e. not subjective/argumentative), which this one does.  I've even listed this as one of the on-topic subjects for the FAQ.  If you agree (or disagree), you should [vote accordingly](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain/123#123).

Comment: +1 - I couldn't have written it better myself

Comment: Hey Aaronut. I've always thought this was one of your rather uncharacteristically nebulous answers. :) Would you mind clarifying it with more specific examples of what _is_ appropriate within the realm of "questions about kitchen equipment are on topic"? e.g. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/773/60

Comment: @hobodave: As both this question and the one you link to reference *specific* questions and ask if those *specific* questions are on/off-topic, I'd prefer to have a separate topic addressing the general issue (a FAQ, like the recipe scope question).

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention to the body of this question, just the title. That makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

I think all kitchen equipments are related to the purpose of this site hence should be allowed. There is also [this discussion](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain) here on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a big difference between asking "What kind of knife makes  easier?" and "What attachments for this particular equipment works overseas?"

I would vote the first on-topic and the second off-topic.

Comment: I tend to agree, the question seems too localised for my liking.