# Appropriate close etiquette?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, closing

I voted to close this question, as it is a call for recipe swapping, which we have in our faq as off-topic: [What should our FAQ contain?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain/126#126)

I'd like to know if I was appropriate in my comments. I said:

> Hi Octonion, welcome to the site! I voted to close this question because we consider recipe requests to be off-topic. If you have any questions, look here: meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/110/…

Is there anything else I should have added? Should I have waited longer before voting to close? Any general tips about close etiquette would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems sufficient.

Comment: I noticed you left a similar comment on a recently-closed question.  Be aware that the "@" is not necessary when replying to a post from the person to whom you're replying.  Users always get notifications of comments on their own questions/answers.

Comment: @Aaronaught, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, I saw your comment on that question, and I thought, "Oh, okay - that's what you're supposed to do when you vote to close a question." You did such a great job addressing the issue with kindness and a reference link, that I took it for the accepted standard.