# Get the FAQ up, please.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Today I told a user to please read the FAQ to understand why recipe questions were off-topic.  He did.  He said it didn't help.  He's right.  One of my biggest issues with the current state of things is that new users are forced to basically find out where the walls are by walking into them. From the FAQ:

- "Food and Cooking - Stack Exchange is for professional and amateur cooks and chefs."
- Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask.
- Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!"

Nothing there about recipes, brewing, growing, local questions, weird snacks... I know the future FAQ has been well discussed and close to consensus on META ([question/110/what-should-our-faq-contain](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain)), but a new user today is no better for it.

Can we fix this by just getting our FAQ up, even if it's in a provisional form that will change over time?

Comment: seems sensible, even if its only an interim, having something is better than the generic one we have now.

Comment: We could even list items by order of votes and say, "Though our official faq is still being worked out, the following is a list of topics in order of support they have received from the community.  The further down on this list, the more likely users will close the question as off-topic, or not appropriate for this site."

Answer (score 2):

### We have a FAQ!

I didn't see any official announcement from the team, but just noticed at a glance that there was an "edit" button in one section.  So I went ahead and added the top-rated entries from the [FAQ proposal](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain), plus one more "on-topic" item to help disambiguate recipe swapping from other recipe questions.

If anyone has any question, comments, thoughts, etc. on the newly-revised [Official FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq), please let me (or any of the other moderators) know.

*Keep in mind that we can only edit the first section on "What kind of questions can I ask here?"  So if you want anything else changed or added, you're out of luck.*

Comment: Nice, looks good!

Comment: I don't see it yet. Has it not propagated to all users or is this just the FAQ for the moderators. ;)

Comment: @yoss: Yea, I just found out that other users cannot see it yet, lol.

Comment: @hobodave, well, at least the moderators will finally be able to get their questions answered!

Comment: Grrrooo, why would this only show up for moderators?  That makes no sense!  I guess the feature is not exactly completed yet!

Comment: @Aaron, probably so you can start to edit it prior to it going live?

Comment: It was a bug.  They fixed it.  Completed for real now!