# Are questions about kitchen safety on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, food-safety

I'll admit, this is spurred by the fact that I burned my hand yesterday while cooking. But there are common cooking situations that relate to kitchen safety -- dealing with burns and cuts, how to safely cut/peel particular foodstuffs, and so on.

I know there is a question that's acceptable on how to peel potatoes better, but would a question about, say, treatment of common kitchen injuries be appropriate? How about how to avoid such injuries? Or, say, how to properly wash your hands if you've got a bandage on them?

I can see argument either way, so I'm interested in what the community will decide.

Comment: Professional cooks keep a bowl of cold oil and a bag of flour near fires. If they burns, very quickly they pass the hand into oil and into fo¡lour. Ans¡d all pass.

Answer (score 9):

Asking how to peel potatoes without slashing your wrists sounds like a fair [food preparation](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain/122#122) question.

Preparing food with bandaged hands could be valid in terms of [food handling / safety](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain/125#125).

Asking how to treat a burn is getting pretty far off-topic - you're probably gonna get better advice on any number of sites dedicated to dispensing medical / first-aid advice. That said, I could see *"How can I quickly treat minor burns without leaving the deep-fryer unattended"* as long as you made it clear that you understand that properly treating *severe* burns should take priority over your fried chicken dinner.

Comment: I agree with this, except for "How can I quickly treat minor burns without leaving the deep-fryer unattended". It's still first aid, and not appropriate here imo. Just about any first aid question could then be manipulated into being on-topic by that standard. "How can I quickly treat an amputated fingertip without leaving my scrambled eggs unattended?"

Comment: @hobodave: yeah, that's probably still not a great example. Was trying to come up with a question on make-shift first aid where answers would be *intentionally* less-than-ideal because of specific constraints (put mustard on your burn and then gloves, that sort of thing). Obviously any first-aid question where the canonical answer is straight out of a textbook wouldn't need to be on-topic.

Comment: These are actually in our FAQ now, so you probably don't need to link to the FAQ proposal thread anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Treatment and prevention of injuries is off-topic. We actually had one question that was broached within this category (can't find link, it has been deleted) about how to treat and prevent mouth burns when eating hot pizza.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  The pizza question is more of an example of how questions about *eating* food as opposed to *cooking* it are generally off-topic.  While I don't think that highly generic questions make sense here, experienced cooks probably *are* some of the best people to answer questions about *cooking-related* injuries.  Especially on the *prevention* front.

Comment: "prevention of injuries" can be implied in "using tools, chemicals and heat correctly", which sounds quite OT.