# Comment on deleted answer

Tags: support, answers, close-reasons

I made an answer on [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73306/how-do-you-know-that-the-cast-iron-seasoning-does-not-leach-into-your-food) question to the effect of "you don't, but it's safe"

Someone commented on it[image]
but the answer has been deleted.

How can I view that comment?

Comment: Can you not see the deleted answer either? Or do you see the answer without the comment? (Trying to figure out if there's a bug here to report or just a mixup.)

Answer (score 3):

sorry about the mixup. I thought that you are able to view comments on your own deleted answers.

I was the one who deleted the answer, and left the comment as an explanation to why it was deleted. Here is the full text:

> Hello Jon, you are discussing the health effects of iron leaching into food. Health discussions are off topic here. If the OP has his own health theory ("I don't want to eat iron"), we can answer whether his habits are aligned with it or not ("your pan leaches iron"). But we don't question such theories or discuss them, or offer alternative theories. – rumtscho♦ 4 hours ago

When you access the desktop version of the site via a browser, you can navigate to the question where your answer used to be. You will see your own deleted answer, together with the comment. If you cannot find the question, there is a small link to your recently deleted posts on your own user profile, you can follow it. See also [this Meta stackexchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47527/are-comments-on-deleted-answers-readable-by-the-poster/47528#47528) for confirmation.

*P.S.* The comment is a short version of a rule we recently documented here on Meta, you can read that [here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/is-it-okay-to-mention-nutrition-in-a-question).