# Are questions about nutrition label calculations on scope?

Tags: support, scope

I have a question about calculating the *actual* sugar used in a sugared fruit preserve fabricated in the EU. The label only provides the nutritional information per 100g of drained (net) weight. The underlying assumption is that the consumer would discard the sugary fruit water, which I have no intention of wasting. I can provide the label, and maybe there is a somewhat reliable method to reverse engineer the nutritional value of the sugary fruit water. Would a question like this be on-topic on Seasoned Advice?

I have read: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1218/89802, but I'm not entirely sure due to concluding from a label that intentionally leaves out some information. Maybe a different stack would be more suited for that type of calculation/approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would consider it on-topic. We do have other questions about nutrition labels. The reason why we have nutrition questions excluded in general is that statements of the type "X is healthy and Y is not" are not objectively agreed upon. Labels involve straightforward calculations. It isn't always clear if all information needed is available to do the calculation, but the question itself is perfectly fine too ask.