# Why is recipe swapping a bad thing?

Tags: recipes

I've gathered that swapping recipes might not fit with the remit of the site.  Is this true, and if so why?

Comment: This kind of discussion belongs on Meta. That link in the upper left hand corner that says "Visit meta". Post there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should "I need a recipe for X?" questions be off-topic?](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic)

Answer (score 3):

Meta thread with all the discussion you might want:

[Should "I need a recipe for X?" questions be off-topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic)

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Better to vote to close as a duplicate than to answer with a link.

Comment: I agree. I ended up doing both because it was taking too long to close. I've no idea why I made it an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This site will only work if we get high quality questions which will attract and challenge high quality expert answerers.  If recipe swaps are allowed then this will create 'noise' in the questions and this will put off experts.

There are already plenty of recipe swap sites.  Use them, if that is what you want.

If you want answers then come here, and use this site.

Unless we get good, regular, questions we will not attract the experts.  If there are high quality, timely answers then people will come here to ask the questions.

It doesn't need to be polluted by pointless discussions which have no answer which distract from the main point of the site.

That's the theory, as I understand it.  I have to admit though it's difficult not to get drawn in to the tempting discussion based questions though.

Comment: I don't want to get too involved in this (duplicate) thread, but I wanted to respond to your final comment: The open-ended discussion questions are tempting precisely *because* they're so easy and open-ended.  Unfortunately, those are precisely the same qualities that make those topics ideal for hobbyist forums, and not an expert Q&A site.  Now is the time when we *need* to be hardasses because we're still defining the boundaries and it's difficult to fully appreciate the long-term negative effects of a super-wide scope when the community is relatively small.

Comment: I agree completely aaronaught, I just wanted to temper my answer  so I didn't seem to be being dictatorial, and show that I understand why people want to ask those questions. Tone can be easily misunderstood on the internet, and it is easy for someone new to come along and ask a question which generates a hostile response because its the 50th recipe harvesting question that day. But to them they just see that they asked a question and got hammered for it, which is likely to drive them away. We have to hand out the inevitable stream of rejections tactfully, which is not always my strong suit

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq) :

What kind of questions should I not ask here?

Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. [Visit our meta-discussion site](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/) where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how Food and Cooking - Stack Exchange works.